# How to compare lazy loading objects of same entity on Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

What's the best way to compare lazy-loaded objects of same entity on Hibernate?

```
//instanceC and instanceD are different objects of different classes

instanceC.getA().equals(instanceD.getA()) // false

instanceC.getA().getId() == insttanceD.getA().getId() // false!
```

So what I do at last is:

```
int idA=instanceC.getA().getId();
int idB=instanceD.getA().getId();

a==b // true
```

And it looks awfully crooked of course. So what I decided at last is to override the `equals()` method and hide this mess.

Is there a better (or a right) solution?

Note: I have checked Stack Overflow question *[Lazy-loaded NHibernate properties in Equals and GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002670)* and some more. I'm not asking for a workaround. I want to put up this question for bringing out a better or the exact solution if any exists.

Comment: Why don't you use a normal string comparison:  `instanceA.getId().equals(instanceB.getId())`?

Comment: You have to create your custom overloaded equals function. Much like the reference you provided.

Comment: @DRCB a String comparison will not work in case a composite key is used.

Comment: @NitinChhajer `==` will not wort either :). Actually I wasn't trying to propose a solution. I was wondering why @kommradHomer uses `==` to compare identifiers. I can only guess that `getId()` returns something like an integer.

Comment: @DRCB , what you suggest works in some cases , yet i mentioned that im not looking for a workaround.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I must be tired.  I don't see the difference between the two cases where you say one is "false !" while the other is "true".  I think you should put a snippet of your Entities with Annotations so we can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing the ids is the right way (but only if there is a unique index in the database on the id column). The unique index assures it is the same entity. (An exception is if you want to compare two instances to see if there are modifications which for example you want to save - then you have to compare all member variables.)

What does `instanceA.getId()` return?

If `int` then

```
instanceC.instanceA.getId()==insttanceD.instanceB.getId()
```

should work well.

If `Integer` then you have to use

```
instanceC.instanceA.getId().equals(insttanceD.instanceB.getId())
```

Might be that was your problem; if not I don't know why the comparison of the ids does not work. I always compare the ids - even with lazy loading - and it works well.

Comment: i dont have a problem. im asking for a generic solution , or the right way , to compare lazy loaded objects of objects.

Comment: That is the general solution - just compare the identifiers, i. e. the primary key. It doesn't make a difference if the instances are loaded with lazy loading or normal loading (at least as long as the session is not closed).

Comment: What type does instanceA.getId() return?

Comment: it should turn int. the other thing should turn int as well. but `a.getC.getId()==b.getC.getId()` is giving false

Comment: It should or it really does? If it really returns int, then the comparison works - it is exactly the same as your 'awfully crooked' solution. With Integer it does not work because if both sides are Integer no unboxing is done.

Comment: it turns int when you assign it to a variable

Comment: Yes, but when you compare it with ==, then it is not assigned to a variable and if it is Integer it does *not* become an int, then you compare the addresses of two Integer object, which can be different even if the int value is the same.

Answer (score 0):

To compare an entity, you always compare on the identifying properties (in most cases, a field named Id). That's a big part of what makes it an entity in the first place.

The id is of course never lazy loaded, so that is not an issue.  Your equals and hashcode of your entity have to be implemented in such a way that they the id and only the id into account.  I believe hibernate even expects this to perform properly.

The normal (and best, if you ask me) way to do this is:

```
equals(Object other){
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o==null) return false;
        if (!Entity.class.isAssignableFrom(other.getClass()) return false;
        Entity otherEntity = (Entity) other;

        if (otherEntity.getId() == getId()) return true;
        if (otherEntity.getId() == null) return false;
        return otherEntity.getId().equals(getId());
}

hashCode(){
   if (getId()) == null return super.hashCode();
   return getId().hashCode();
}
```

Comment: well. the Id comparison is giving me false . and yes , even the Id is not loaded on lazy loading entities.

Comment: In that case, debug why your id comparision is failing.  Are you sure the ids are correctly handled (the same)?  As a general rule, do not lazy load your ids (I would expect hibernate can't even do this).

Comment: there may be a misunderstanding. can you check the code in the question again ?

Comment: why don't you use instanceC.getA().getId().equals(insttanceD.getA().getId()) ?

Comment: i can. i can use other things too. i dont look for a work around. i manage to do what i want in several ways. I say ,  I want to put up this question for bringing out a better or the exact solution if any exists.

Comment: @kommradHomer I added an example to the reply then.